# Impossible to test Checkout.com with Laravel Dusk

Tags: selenium-webdriver, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to test the payment process of my website using Checkout.com (https://www.checkout.com/).
For the test, I'm using Laravel Dusk, so Facebook/WebDriver.
But I don't succeed to access to the iframe or the input of checkout. Impossible to get it with selector or other.
Some of you get an idea ? 
Thx

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is going wrong? Could you edit your question to reflect what are you trying, and what is happening?